# Parsing in C#, or possibly a tweak to Global Group detector

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm trying to run through a list of global groups a user belongs to, and determine whether or not they belong to a specific group.  I've got this code which I found somewhere (possibly here) with a few minor tweaks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ClientDPL
{
    public partial class WebFormX : Page  
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {

            string strUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            string username = strUserName.Substring(strUserName.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
            string MyGlobalGroup = "L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH";

            List<string> userNestedMembership = new List<string>();  

            DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry(); // Use this to query the default domain
            //DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com", "username", "password"); // Use this to query a remote domain

            DirectorySearcher samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();  

            samSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;  
            samSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" + username + ")";  
            samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");  

            SearchResult samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();  

            if (samResult != null)  
            {  
                DirectoryEntry theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();  
                theUser.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });  

                foreach (byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"])  
                {  
                    System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier mySID = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(resultBytes, 0);  

                    DirectorySearcher sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();  

                    sidSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;  
                    sidSearcher.Filter = "(objectSid=" + mySID.Value + ")";  
                    sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");  

                    SearchResult sidResult = sidSearcher.FindOne();  

                    if (sidResult != null)  
                    {  
                        userNestedMembership.Add((string)sidResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]);  
                    }  
                }

                int X = 0;

                foreach (string myEntry in userNestedMembership)  
                {  
                    //Console.WriteLine(myEntry);
                    X = X + 1;
                    if (myEntry == MyGlobalGroup)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubmitWork, typeof(Button), "Data Entry", "alert('You are a member of ' + MyEntry)", true);
                        return;
                    }
                }  

            }  
            else 
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("The user doesn't exist");  
            }  

            //Console.ReadKey();  

        }

        protected void btnSubmitWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This runs fine.  However, when I get to this part:

```
foreach (string myEntry in userNestedMembership)  
{  
    //Console.WriteLine(myEntry);
    X = X + 1;
    if (myEntry == MyGlobalGroup)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubmitWork, typeof(Button), "Data Entry", "alert('You are a member of ' + MyEntry)", true);
        return;
    }
}
```

myEntry is giving me something that looks like this:

> CN=L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH,OU=ALOSup,OU=Infra,DC=internal,
>   DC=mycompany,DC=com

What I really need is just the **CN** piece, or

> L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH

Is there a way to extract this piece from that string, or tweak my code so that myEntry only returns that one bit of information?

Comment: string cn = myEntry.Split(',').Select(e => new { Key = e.Split('=')[0], Value = e.Split('=')[1] }).First(e => e.Key == "CN").Value;

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and grouping to extract information from such a string :

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"(CN)\=(.+)\,";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: So, given the code I have posted above, how would I integrate this?

Comment: copy paste :) Input is your "CN=L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH,OU=ALOSup,OU=Infra,DC=internal, DC=mycompany,DC=com" and match.Groups[1].Value should be "L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH"

Comment: Gotcha.  What would be the proper Reference I need in order for it to understand Regex?  Right now the words **MatchCollection** and **Regex** are underlined red.

Comment: Unfortunately, match.Groups[1].Value seems to always resolve to "CN", and match.Groups[2].Value resolves to everything **but** "CN".

Comment: hmm lets experiment with the pattern try changing it to @"CN\=(.+)\,"

Comment: ?match.Groups[1].Value is now **L_WDJACK127_WDC_SSIS_USER_CH,OU=ALOSup,OU=Infra,DC=internal, DC=mycompany**.